# Multiple Xauthority files generated in home directory

Tags: xorg, xubuntu, home-directory

```
tom@tom-pc:~$ ls -lrta .Xa*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom  0 May 23 23:45 .Xauthority.RM2HXW
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom  0 May 24 09:06 .Xauthority.CS6HXW
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom  0 May 24 16:51 .Xauthority.BYMIXW
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom  0 May 24 23:22 .Xauthority.F13LXW
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom  0 May 25 23:55 .Xauthority.FWY3XW
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom  0 May 27 18:52 .Xauthority.Z936XW
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom  0 May 28 08:54 .Xauthority.IGGQXW
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom  0 May 28 22:41 .Xauthority.874LXW
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom  0 May 29 08:49 .Xauthority.LQQWXW
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tom tom 51 May 29 18:02 .Xauthority
```

From looking at the timestamps, a new one seems to be generated every time I turn off my computer (or log off). Where are they coming from? How can I stop these from being generated?
I'm running xubuntu 13.04.
Thanks